# Core Data - save in background thread and fetch in main thread

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, core-data, ios6

I am new to CoreData and in my current application I want to be able to parse and save the data to CoreData in a background thread. Also, at the same time, I want to be able to perform fetch on the main thread to update the UI.

Currently everything is happening in main thread so it hangs the application and has very poor user experience.

Any pointers would be helpful, like from where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into parent / child contexts. http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ here you can find a code sample.